# How Class Method can access Instance Method ?

Tags: objective-c

I am from Actionscript Background. In Actionscript Class Method can access only Class Methods and Class properties.

But In Objective C,

1. How Class method gameResultAll can access Instance Method initFromPlist

   ```
   +(NSMutableArray *)gameResultAll://Class Method

   -(id)initFromPlist:(id)plist;//Instance Method

   NSMutableArray *gameResults = [GameResult gameResultAll]; // (returns GameResult array)
   ```
2. Why [self init] method is called instead of [super init] to create an instance from class method.

Thanks in advance.

```
#import "GameResult.h"

@implementation GameResult

#define GAME_RESULT_KEY @"gameresult_key"
#define SCORE_KEY @"score"

+(NSMutableArray *)gameResultAll
{

    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id plist in [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:GAME_RESULT_KEY] mutableCopy] allValues]) 
    {
        GameResult *gameResult = [[GameResult alloc] initFromPlist:plist];
        [resultArray addObject:gameResult];
    }
    return  resultArray;
}

//Designated initialiser
-(id)initFromPlist:(id)plist
{

    self = [self init];
    if(self)
    {
       if([plist isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
       {
           NSDictionary *resultDictionary = (NSDictionary*)plist;
           _score = (int)resultDictionary[SCORE_KEY];
       }
    }
    return  self;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 lololol I was just going to say that

Comment: sorry guys, i am using first time. I updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> How Class method `gameResultAll` can access Instance Method `initFromPlist`

It can access that method because you used the [`alloc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-alloc) method, which creates an instance of `GameResult`. Now that you have an instance, you can use instance methods in conjunction with this instance.

By the way, this is a very common pattern, a "convenience" class method that allocates an instance of an object (with `alloc`) and initializes the object (with `init` or some permutation of that). Or, as in this case, it can create an array of these objects.

You then go on to ask:

> Why `[self init]` method is called instead of `[super init]` to create an instance from class method.

I can understand the confusion, but there is an important, yet subtle distinction in the behavior of these two.

Imagine this scenario:

- At some future date, you subclass `GameResult`, e.g. `ArcadeGameResult`;
- You implemented an `init` method for `ArcadeGameResult` that initializes some properties unique to this subclass; and
- You happen to initialize a `ArcadeGameResult` instance like so:

  ```
  ArcadeGameResult *agr = [[ArcadeGameResult alloc] initFromPlist:plist];
  ```

Because the `initFromPlist` uses `[self init]`, it means that the the `initFromPlist` method of `GameResult` will end up calling the `init` method of the object (which in this example, is actually a `ArcadeGameResult` object). But if `initFromPlist` in `GameResult` called `[super init]` instead, it would *not* have called `ArcadeGameResult`'s `init` method and thus `initFromPlist` would be problematic if ever used in conjunction with a subclass.

Bottom line, unless the method you're calling is the *exact* same method signature, it's safer to call the `self` rendition rather than the `super` rendition. It's a little more flexible in case you ever decide to subclass in the future.

---

There is a corollary to the counsel. When calling class methods from an instance method, you should refer to `[self class]` rather than the class name. So, imagine your `GameResult` class had a class method:

```
+ (void)someClassMethod
{
    // do something
}
```

If you had some `GameResult` instance method that was going to avail itself of this method, you might be tempted to write:

```
- (void)someInstanceMethod
{
    // do some stuff

    [GameResult someClassMethod];
}
```

But that's not a good idea. You would instead use the following:

```
- (void)someInstanceMethod
{
    // do some stuff

    [[self class] someClassMethod];
}
```

They look very similar, but the latter lets you implement a `someClassMethod` in a subclass, and this instance method will still work. If you use the former construct, the subclassed class method wouldn't be called by `someInstanceMethod`.

These are subtle issues, and probably not critical for your current code sample. But hopefully it illuminates the choice of `[self init]` versus `[super init]` in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

> In Actionscript Class Method can access only Class Methods and Class properties.

That's not different in Objective-C either (because nothing else would make sense), so:

> How Class method GameResultAll can access Instance Method initFromPlist

Only through a valid instance.

> Why `[self init]` method is called instead of `[self super]` to create an instance from class method.

Because the latter is a syntax error, perhaps? Read a basic Objective-C tutorial.